# Flutter : retreive documents from Firestore in stream

Tags: android, stream, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retreive documents from my message collection; but i don't get the result and i have no error from flutter. Here ise my code

```
      body:  new Center(
    child: new StreamBuilder(
        stream:  Firestore.instance.collection("messages").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Chargement ...");
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index)=> new Text("papa"),
          );

        }
    ),
  )
```

and here  is my firebase database 
[image: firebase]

Comment: Your Document don't seems to have any field(key:vaule) only contain reference to another Collection with same document name.

Comment: how can i get all the collections

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Text(document['papa'])`

Check docs: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: i put new Text("papa") to just see how many times it will show it, it isnot dynamic